# How to compress syslog-ng's network link, now that zlib is disabled in openssl?

Tags: 14.04, networking, openssl, compression

In our servers infrastructure, for logging, we use a client/server setup, using syslog-ng, and stunnel as a mean of compression at the network level, through zlib at the SSL layer (syslog-ng doesn't support over the wire compression on the OSE edition - they lie on their website).

Upon installing Ubuntu 14.04, I've found that the 1.0.1f-1ubuntu1 version of OpenSSL entirely disabled compression, which makes the stunnel layer pointless, and leaves the infrastructure without network-level compression (which is crucial).

Is there any suggestion on how to cleanly work this around? I have a few thoughts:

- given the OpenSSL developments, I don't think it would be safe to downgrade
- given that the pace of security fixes increased, it wouldn't be feasible to build the package manually
- I don't know any alternative for compressing the network connection of syslog-ng.

Is it expected for OpenSSL to re-enable the (zlib) compression?

Answer (score 1):

syslog-ng OSE doesn't support on-the-wire compression at the moment. If you would like to see this feature in OSE, a good start would be to open a github issue to notify the developers about it: https://github.com/balabit/syslog-ng/issues

BTW, where does the syslog-ng website state that syslog-ng OSE supports on-the-wire compression? I haven't found it now, but would gladly correct it so others do not misunderstand it.

Regards,

Robert Fekete

syslog-ng documentation maintainer

Comment: The page is https://www.balabit.com/network-security/syslog-ng/comparing/detailed - there is an entry "Support for network link compression when using TLS" is checked under the OSE version.